# How to calculate this integral (with limit afterwards)?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, extrapolation

I have to calculate this integral with limit:

$$ G(m,n; E) = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \iint_{-\pi}^{+\pi}  d k_x d k_y  \frac{e^{i(k_x m + k_y n)}}{E+ i \epsilon + 2\cos k_x + 2\cos k_y } . $$

Here $m$, $n$ are integers and $E$ is some real number.

The problem is that the integrand can diverge if $-4< E <  4$.

My idea is to first set $\epsilon $ to some finite value, and then somehow extrapolate the value to the limit $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+}$.

I do not need to calculate the integral analytically. Actually, numerical approach is preferred.

Comment: For m=-n the integral could be given in terms of elliptic functions

Regarding the divergence, you can handle them by letting $\epsilon$ finite until the end of the calculation, where it will translate into $\delta$-functions and principle parts.